python dict is giving key error even if initialized with some values
data={}
vega={}
for coin in ['BTC']:
    vega[coin] = {}
    data[coin] = {}
    data[coin]['columns']=['27-Apr-24', '28-Apr-24', '29-Apr-24', '03-May-24', '10-May-24', '17-May-24', '31-May-24']
    for expiry in data[coin]['columns']:
        vega[coin][expiry] = data[coin].get('Vega', {}).get('Total', {}).get(expiry, 0)

for coin in ['BTC']:
    data[coin]['columns']=['27-Apr-24', '28-Apr-24', '29-Apr-24', '03-May-24', '10-May-24', '17-May-24', '31-May-24', '28-Jun-24']
    for expiry in data[coin]['columns']:
        vega[coin][expiry] += data[coin].get('Vega', {}).get('Total', {}).get(expiry, 0)

Im initializing dict, and giving values if key is not present.
But however, getting
KeyError: '28-Jun-24'

on last line why?
Could someone help me figure out mistake im doing here?

this part: vega[coin][expiry] +=. The operator += repeats the left side. Example: x += 1 is the same of x = x + 1. If you don't have x initialized you will get this error. You can do something as vega[coin][expiry] = vega.get(coin, {}).get(expiry, 0) + data[coin].get('Vega', {}).get('Total', {}).get(expiry, 0)

in first there is no expiry of 28-June, in second there is. Can we fix this with default dict?

You could use vega[coin] = collections.defaultdict(int) in the first loop.

Just change from
vega[coin][expiry] += data[coin].get('Vega', {}).get('Total', {}).get(expiry, 0)

to
vega[coin][expiry] = vega.get(coin, {}).get(expiry, 0) + data[coin].get('Vega', {}).get('Total', {}).get(expiry, 0)

and you will not get the error.
But, notice that you didn't initialize it with 28-Jun-24.

This works and fixes, but could you also help me with default dict here?

Take a look here, it might help. Try to implement it and post your problems on StackOverflow.

This code is somewhat redundant, anyway a quick solution is to add '28-Jun-24' in the first data[coin]['columns'] assignment.
data[coin]['columns']=['27-Apr-24', '28-Apr-24', '29-Apr-24', '03-May-24', '10-May-24', '17-May-24', '31-May-24','28-Jun-24']

This will work
